# Django password help_text not rendering correctly

Tags: django, forms, rendering

I am rendering a simple signup form as follows:

```
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
        <p>
          {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
          {{ field }}
          {% if field.help_text %}
            <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
          {% endif %}
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </p>
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>
```

However, the help text for the password, which is an unordered list, is rendering as a single string (including the markup).

[image]

It is basically putting the entire ul in quotes as can be seen from the shot from dev tools.

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: How are you defining that field? Show the code for the form.

Answer (score 1):

Use [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) template tag:

```
<small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</small>
```